# How to install solr-4.6.1 on ubuntu using tomcat7?

Tags: solr, installation, tomcat7, search-engine

I want step by step instructions for installation of solr search engine using tomcat7 on ubuntu. I searched on google but I am not getting proper reference. Please help me to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Download Solr dist: [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.6.1/solr-4.6.1.zip). Unzip it anywhere.

2- find $EXTRACTEDDIR/solr/dist/solr-4.6.1.war and copy it to the location you want to configure solr.

3- configure the solr.xml as explained [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml). You will need to change your hostport to 8080(or what ever port tomcat7 is configured) and put it where you put solr-4.6.1.war

4- create /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml and put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="$SOLRBASE/solr-4.6.1.war" debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
        <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="$SOLRBASE" override="true" />
</Context>
```

replace SOLRBASE with the loacation you put solr.war and solr.xml.

5- copy $EXTRACTEDDIR/example/lib/ext/* . * to /usr/share/tomcat7/lib(for loging libs)

6- give permissions of the folder where you put solr.war and solr.xml to "tomcat7" user.

7- restart tomcat and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

1. copy the solr files to ubuntu.
2. copy the file "solr.war" into "%tomcat_home%/webapps/" and add the  solr service's context to the "%tomcat_home%/server.xml"
3. set the environment value "solr/home" int server.xml or web.xml

visit here for detail:https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

it's a piece of cake, may you succeed!